# Why preprocessor directives not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, preprocessor

I'm trying to create variable for the device as per the version but my control is always going to the else part. My iOS is 9.3

```
#if os(iOS) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 90000
    var addressBookRef : CNContactStore? = nil
#else
    var addressBookRef : ABAddressBook? = nil
#endif
```

I've also tried this as suggested [here](http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/) but `defined` not taking in `Swift2.x`

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 90000
    var addressBookRef : CNContactStore? = nil
#else
    var addressBookRef : ABAddressBook? = nil
#endif
```

When I'm checking at the run time and using breakpoints, I can see that my control always going to else portion and variable `addressBookRef` is of type `ABAddressBook`.

Suggest please what wrong I'm doing

Comment: If you use **#if** don't forget add **#endif**

Comment: I'm doing that, sorry I did not add that here. Forgot. let me update

Comment: Refer this http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/

Answer (score 3):

You cannot check the version of iOS with a directive, you need to check this at runtime.

If you are using iOS 8.0 or later you can use this:

```
let os = NSProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersion
switch (os.majorVersion, os.minorVersion, os.patchVersion) {
case (8, 0, _):
    // 8.0.0 and < 8.1.0
case (8, _, _):
    // 8.1.0 and < 9.0
case (9, _, _):
    // 9.0.0
default:
    //
}
```

You can also use `UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion` which will also work on iOS 7:

```
switch UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare("8.0.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) {
case .OrderedSame, .OrderedDescending:
    // >= 8.0
case .OrderedAscending:
    // < 8.0
}
```